Toxiproxy не получается замедлить работу сервера
Я использую toxiproxy 2.1.1 на своем линукс сервере. На нем работает приложение которое на атомате отправляет тхт файлы из одной папки в другую в случае если они появляются. Я пытаюсь создать прокси и клиента чтобы замедлять эти запросы и спровоцировать таймауты.
сервер мой my-lab-dev:12345
вот примеры прокси и токсиков что я создаю
Прокси:
curl -X POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8474/proxies' \
    -d '{
        "name": "example",
        "listen": "my-lab-dev:12345",
        "upstream": "0.0.0.0:5000"
    }'

Токсик:
curl -X POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8474/proxies/example/toxics' \
    -d '{
        "name": "latency_toxic",
        "type": "latency",
        "toxicity": 1.0,
        "attributes": {
            "latency": 30000,
            "jitter": 1000
        }
    }'

Ну и запускаю я токси-сервер командой toxiproxy-sever ничего особого, все как в документации. Лежит файл для запуска линуксового токси в папке usr/local/bin
Права на исполнения я выдал.
Но при работе приложения на серверах судя по логам вообще никакого замедления нет, не говоря уже о тайм ауте эксепшене, даже если ставить latency на час.
В чем ошибка?
